Does the image generator work in the free version of ChatGPT?
I am using the free version of ChatGPT. Recently, the image generator has appeared there. However, I couldn't generate even one image with it. I always get this result:

Me: Generate image of a football on green grass
ChatGPT: I can't create images right now. Can I help you with something else?


Could anyone say if the image generator works in the free version of ChatGPT and, if yes, how to fix it?


Does image generator work in free version of ChatGPT?

Yes, example:

Sometimes features are rolled out progressively.
